# Azure cognitive search indexer blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, indexer

I am stuck in a complicated situation and appreciate that if somebody can help.

So I was testing indexing blob storage( pdf files) and indexed a copy of my storage in qa environment that cost me some money.

My question is that:
Is there any solution to use this index in production without indexing again?

I found a solution to copy the index and that works fine but when I add an indexer that is connect to production blob storage it start indexing from scratch again( as I expected). Is there any solution to avid this? Is there any solution to ask indexer to index from now on?

I tried to use the index and the indexer that I already have by changing the subscription to prod. But I have to change the data source for indexer to point at production blob storage and in this case I get an error :

*Indexer 'filesIndexer' currently references data source 'qafilesds' and cannot be updated to reference a different datasource 'prodfilesds' because it has a non-empty change tracking state, or it is currently in progress. You can use Reset API to reset the indexer's change tracking state when it is no longer in progress, and retry this call.*

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to your first question is to simply use the qa index you built.

A more complicated answer is to switch from the push model you are using now to a pull model. From your explanation above I assume all of your content comes from blob storage. And you have configured an indexer to do the indexing for you. This is known as the pull model.

The alternative is to use the Azure Cognitive Search SDK to write your own application that submits content to the index instead. In this case you do not use the built-in indexer, only the index itself. Then you are free to use whatever logic you want to determine what to index and what to skip. You can even enable your storage accounts to notify your application with events when content is updated.